# How to change recurring meeting series without cancelling exceptions

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

in Outlook 2010. I have a recurring meeting series. In the series I have made a couple of exceptions by manually editing specific calendar entries in the series - so on specific days the time if the meeting changes.

Now I want to change the end date but when I do I get the message "Any exceptions associated with this recurring appointment will be cancelled. Is this OK?"

If I say "OK". All the meetings return to a uniform series all starting at the same time, and I again have to go and manually edit the specific dates that need to change to a different time.

Is there a way to change the end date without

Answer (score 10):

In 2022, this can be accomplished if you have Office 365.

1. Log in to Office 365 and navigate to your Calendar.
2. Find and click the first future instance of the meeting that you want to change.
3. At the bottom left is the Edit dropdown. In Office 365 this offers the option to change "This and all following events." Select that and make your changes.

   [image: Meeting invitation Edit dropdown]

Tested with Office 365 and verified changes from Office 2016 desktop client.

Thanks to Jen M's 2020 [comment](http://web.archive.org/web/20220819192846/https://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2008/12/change-outlook-recurring-appointments-without-losing-exceptions/comment-page-2/) on a blog post from 2008.

Comment: "Member for 8 years, 8 months" but apparently this is my first contribution to this particular stack other than commenting and voting, so "New contributor" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

*Speaking from experience...*

Because it is a recurring series, they are all tied together, making it so it is not possible to save those individual changes when modifying the series.

As a work around, you can delete the occurrences which are the exceptions, make separate meetings for them, then change the series without affecting the meetings with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what I now know (after googling this), there seems to be a workaround using the Android app. (This is German though, couldn't find it in English. https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/msoffice/forum/all/serientermin-f%C3%BCr-zuk%C3%BCnftige-termine/05f49b9a-b65a-4346-9e12-6324b9ff6264 )

But, for me, in the future I will not create eternal series anymore, but rather time-limit it and create a new series afterwards, so changes are small and future meetings are easier to manually delete.

Also, there seems to be (now) an Office 365-only solution, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/stop-a-recurring-calendar-meeting-in-outlook/216940c8-a9d6-47e0-b081-8019fc92e624 .

Handling seems counter intuitive and generally poor. I used to keep meeting notes in the calender. Gone they are after changing the end-date or anything else.

Comment: I am using Office 365 and that option doesn't show up for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in 2022.
When changing the meeting time, edit the series and choose the reoccurring end date to be the last meeting that you had. Before saving and sending the update, Create a new meeting occurrence with the start date of your next scheduled meeting day with the new time. Copy over all of the fields and attendees from the previous meeting details. Save and send the update for both.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).